# How does IIS 7.5's Rewrite Rules thing actually work?

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've imported my mod_rewrite rules... everything works just fine... but seemingly randomly it deletes them all.

I've been moving some files around in wwwroot... so, my question is this:

When I import rewrite rules, does it create a new file somewhere in wwwroot that I happen to be moving/deleting every time?

Thanks for any help you can give me :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

When you import rules, it is stored in "web.config" in wwwroot. If you delete this, you delete your rules... ;).

Comment: One web.config to rule them all, One web.config to find them,
One web.config to bring them all and in the darkness bind them

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty cool that EVERYTHING rides on this one file. ;)

Comment: Personally I would prefer if IIS kept it settings somewhere other than the file that configures my app.